# how to pass argv parameters in GUI program c++, not console?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

folks.

i want pass argv parameters in my GUI program which written c++, my program is not the black screen console, but it is a GUI.
for example my program is AAA.exe, and i want to pass a command like "AAA.exe doThing" etc. how can i do it? thank you all so much.

Comment: [WinMain: The Application Entry Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thank you, i get the answer.

Comment: Pass them in exactly the same way. Perhaps your question is how to read them.

Answer (score 3):

While `WinMain` is the application entry point, it does not help you very much with command line arguments.

(You can get the command line from anywhere using [GetCommandLine()](https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+GetCommandLine).)

You can parse it using [CommandLineToArgvW()](https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=msdn+CommandLineToArgvW).

Comment: thank you, i got it and came up following answers. i have tested it, working as arrow...

Answer (score 1):

If you use VS you can easily use [__argc and __argv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv).

These variables are automatically populated by the CRT. The variables are available in an MBCS/ANSI version and an Unicode version. __argv is the MBCS/ANSI version, whereas __wargv is the unicode version.

To use them we have just to include stdlib.h. there is also a __targv version available when you include TCHAR.h.

Comment: There is no ASCII version. There is an ANSI version, tough.

Comment: You are right! I corrected my answer.

Comment: You still have "_argv is the ascii version_".

Comment: Changed it again!

Comment: "__arcg" is a typo. It should be __argc, of course.

Answer (score -2):

came up with following answers, it was tested and working nicely as arrow.
added this code in WinMain block.

```
LPWSTR *szArgList;
int argCount;

 szArgList = CommandLineToArgvW((LPWSTR)GetCommandLine(), &argCount);
 if (szArgList == NULL){
     MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to parse command line", "Error", MB_OK);
     return 10;
 }
 int wint = 1;
 for(int i = 0; i < argCount; i++){
    cout << "szArgList[i]: " << (LPSTR)szArgList[i] << endl;
    string argsbek= (LPSTR)szArgList[i];
    if (argsbek.find(" passMyword") != string::npos){
       cout <<"words are passed ..."<<endl;
       wint=2;
    }
 }
 LocalFree(szArgList);
```

Comment: The casts will surely silence the compiler. But once you run the program, you'll see that it fails. Use `GetCommandLineW()` and `wcout`, and drop the casts. You should probably also remove all the unrelated code.

Comment: Nope, this code is no good.

Comment: Great, thank you very much.